# Get values of dynamic fields and radio button

Tags: angularjs

can you give ideas or suggestions about this problem.
im creating four radio buttons per question(a multiple choice question basically)and they are generated dynamically. if i created 3 questions that are multiple choice, 3 multiple choices will be displayed in my questionnaire. 
if 3 multiple choice questions exist, 3 questions x 4 radio buttons = 12 radio buttons.  this means i have a 3 set radio group consisting of four radio buttons.  my problem, how can i get the values selected in the 3 sets of radio group?

```
php code:
          echo "<li><input type='radio' name='radio' value='a' class='answer multiple'/>choice</li>";
          echo "<li><input type='radio' name='radio' value='b' class='answer multiple'/>choice</li>";
          echo "<li><input type='radio' name='radio' value='c' class='answer multiple'/>choice</li>";
          echo "<li><input type='radio' name='radio' value='d' class='answer multiple'/>choice</li>";
```

Comment: Follow this link, exact same as you want : [Exact answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166270/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-checked-radio-button-when-submitting-a-form-using)

Comment: Do you want to do it in AngularJS?

Comment: @Maverick : He has already given tag of angular js

Comment: @Maverick yes im using anguarjs. i want to get those 3 values selected in 3 radio groups. do you have any idea how can i do that?

Comment: @Jigar7521 the link you gave has a only 1 radio group. however, i have 3 radio groups which are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using ng-repeat to create multiple questions and then a nested ng-repeat to display the choices

[Here is the plnkr for the same](http://plnkr.co/edit/pnFpr6MUPlv8lXYjSnY6?p=preview)

```
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <p><label>{{question.title}}</label></p>
    <div ng-repeat="choice in question.choices"><input type="radio" ng-name="question.title" ng-model="radioValue[$parent.$index]" ng-value="choice">{{choice}} </div>
  </div>
```

AngularJS Code

```
$scope.questions = [{id:1, title:'Question 1', choices:['Apple','Orange','Mango','Guava']},
                    {id:2, title:'Question 2', choices:['Apple2','Orange2','Mango2','Guava2']},
                    {id:3, title:'Question 3', choices:['Apple3','Orange3','Mango3','Guava3']}]
   $scope.radioValue =[];
```